# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Pool'. Property 'config' is missing in type '{}'

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this intellisense error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Pool'. Property 'config' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Below are the pictures to give a better overview of what is happening.
I've tried for around 2 hours to understand why vs code intellisense is complaining here.
maybe another insight could help me solve this problem.

Of course if I change the return type to any the error will go away but that's not what I want. The function declaration says the return type should be Pool, and that's what I'm expecting a Promise of Pool object.

I guess it's something really silly that I'm not aware of.
therefore I would appricate any explanation or even direction.

thank you all and have a nice day,

**Partial of class without error**

[image]

**Partial of class with error**

[image]

**Mysql node library**

[image]

**tsconfig.json**

[image]

**createPool mysql node lib declaration file**

[image]

Sourcecode, slightly modified:

```
export class Database
{
...

    private static pool: Pool;

    public static async connect(): Promise<Pool>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (Database.pool) {
                return resolve(Database.pool);
            }

            let config: PoolConfig = {
                connectTimeout: 15,
                connectionLimit: 10,
                host: process.env.TEST_DB_HOST || 'localhost',
                user: process.env.TEST_DB_USER || 'root',
                password: process.env.TEST_DB_PASSWORD || '',
                database: process.env.TEST_DB_DATABASE || 'test'
            };

            const pool: Pool = createPool(config);

            pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                connection.release();

                return resolve(pool);
            });
        });
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't add `async` unless you use `await`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told TypeScript what the type of the resolution of the `Promise` is, and apparently it can't infer it. Change:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
```

to

```
return new Promise<Pool>((resolve, reject) => 
// ---------------^^^^^^
```